# Mysql LIKE script isn't working

Tags: mysql, jquery

I have a simple query that is suppose to take user inputted text and find words matching like a search engine.  I use jquery's post function to take this data and send it to a tags.php for processing. However, nothing is echoed out.  I think my sql statement may be wrong.  im pretty sure my database has keywords that match the input string.

PHP:

```
$tags=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tags']);
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag LIKE '%$tags%'");
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($num_rows == 0){
echo "<div class='result'>No Results</div>";
}
else{
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo "<div>$row['tag']</div>";
}

}
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#tagsInput').keyup(function(){

        var tags = $(this).val();
        if (tags==''){
            $('#tagResult').css("display" , "none");
        }
        else{
            $('#tagResult').css("display" , "block");

                $.post('../tags.php' , {tags: tags} , function(response){

                $('#tagResult').html(response);     
                });
            }
    });
```

Comment: does "No Results" show up...?

Comment: What makes you believe that this is a problem with your query?  Is the AJAX call completing?

Comment: @Sudhir no results does not show up

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs nothing shows up. the css does take effect though

Comment: is your post url valid.. did you check the console...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and paste your while loop with this one :

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo "<div>".$row['tag']."</div>";
}
```

Comment: +1 good catch, but I'm not happy with the completeness of the question.